# Custom Routing in ASP .NET Core Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I love the areas feature in ASP .NET Core.

For example, the admin section resides inside ~/Areas/Admin folder which has it's own Views, Controllers and Models inside it. An example route for the admin area is **/domain.com/admin/users/manage**

Say I have another area called Customers which can contain all customer related stuff. The customer area will have function related to CRUD operations only. So I need the route for customer area be like **domain.com/customer/create**. But as far as I know the only way to achieve this is through placing the views inside the common Views folder.

Is there any way to organize the customer related stuff in the Areas folder and access it through the url I mentioned above?

Answer (score 0):

I find the easiest way is using attribute route, you have to enable it first inside RouteConfig.cs for ASP.NET MVC. In ASP.NET core, i am not sure you have to enable it or not, i belive it is inside Startup.cs?

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    //routes.AppendTrailingSlash = false;
    //routes.LowercaseUrls = true;
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    ....
}
```

Now in your customer area controller

```
[RouteArea("Customer", AreaPrefix = "")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    //Customer/Create
    [Route("Customer/Create")]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {

    }
}
```

RouteArea is the Area name, setting the prefix to null so it won't show up in the url as Customer/Customer/Create, Route is the Controller Action Name, in this case the result will be Customer/Create

Comment: When I put the [RouteArea("Customer", AreaPrefix = "")] part, I am getting the error type or namespace not found.